# How to determine if two (irreducible) polynomials give rise to the same (field) ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Write down all polynomials of exactly degree $3$ over $\Bbb F_2$. How many different rings $\Bbb F_2[x]/\langle f\rangle$ can we form up to isomorphism, and which of these are fields.
\begin{align*}
&x^3=xxx\\
&x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2+x+1)\\
&x^3+x=x(x+1)(x+1)\\
&x^3+x+1\text{ gives rise to a field}\\
&x^3+x^2=x^2(x+1)\\
&x^3+x^2 +1 \text{ gives rise to a field}\\
&x^3+x^2+x=x(x^2+x+1)\\
&x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x+1)(x+1)
\end{align*}

How do I determine if any of these polynomials give rise to the same ring, and how do I determine if the two fields are isomorphic?

---

The fields both give rise to a finite group of order $8=2^3$ and are hence isomorphic.

Comment: In general, two finite fields with the same number of elements are isomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How could they determine the same ring? The first, namely $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3)$, is a local ring, while $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+1)$ is not. In fact, by CRT we have $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+1)\simeq\mathbb F_2\times\mathbb F_4$. The next ring is $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X)\simeq\mathbb F_2\times\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^2)$, and the second factor is not a field. However, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X^2)$ (also by CRT). We also have $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X+1)^3\simeq\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3)$ and $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X^2+X)\simeq\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+1)$.

As an example, let's show that $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X)\simeq\mathbb F_2\times\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^2)$: we have two ideals, $I=(X)$ and $J=((X+1)^2)$ which are comaximal since $\gcd(X,(X+1)^2)=1$. By CRT we get $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^3+X)\simeq\mathbb F_2[X]/(X)\times\mathbb F_2[X]/((X+1)^2)\simeq\mathbb F_2\times\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^2)$. (The last isomorphism is given by $X\mapsto X+1$.)

Comment: Could you demonstrate using CRT once here please, I have to recap it, but it would be nice to see an example in this context, if not it's a great answer regardless, thanks